# Can I upload wordpress plugin made with framework

Tags: plugins, framework

I would like to create plugin based on framework - http://wpmvc.org. 
Will my plugin be accepted in wordpress plugin directory ?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to wordpress.stackexchange.com.

I don't think plugins with frameworks are allowed, sorry.

https://wptavern.com/the-wordpress-plugin-directory-will-no-longer-accept-frameworks

https://make.wordpress.org/plugins/2016/03/01/please-do-not-submit-frameworks/

Here are **Detailed Plugin Guidelines**
https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/detailed-plugin-guidelines/

And here about **Writing a Plugin**
https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin

If this answer helped you or solved your issue please vote and/or mark it accepted, thank you.

Comment: 2 answers and both are different, which one should I trust ?

Comment: If you read [Please do not submit frameworks](https://make.wordpress.org/plugins/2016/03/01/please-do-not-submit-frameworks/) that @lowtechsun referenced, you'll see that it says: "Frameworks and libraries should be packaged with each plugin (hopefully in a way that doesn’t conflict with other plugins using the framework or libraries). At least until core supports plugin dependencies."

That whole post makes clear that what is not allowed is frameworks in the form of plugin, not plugins that use/bundle frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a framework to build your plugin.

What you can't do, is submit a plugin that's just the framework itself (so that others can require your plugin as a dependency, for example).

Using a framework will neither get your plugin automatically approved nor rejected. It will depend though, on your adherence to the [Plugin Guidelines.](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/detailed-plugin-guidelines/)

Comment: 2 answers and both are different, which one should I trust ?